# How to authorize from an especific policy in pundit (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

Is there a way to specify the policy class in the `authorization` method in `Pundit`? When you do

```
    authorize @user, :show
```

It uses the `UserPolicy` class, because `@user` is a `User` (Model) instance. Does anybody know a way to perform the `authorize` method on another policy class? like `CustomerPolicy`, without the existence of the `Customer` model class.

Comment: https://github.com/elabs/pundit#headless-policies

Comment: Nice, was right there (noob). Just add that if the policy is namespaced then you'll need to give an array of symbols with the namespaces, like if you got `People::CustomerPolicy`, then the authorize will be `authorize [:people, :customer]`. If helps somebody :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a symbol instead of a model instance to invoke a "headless" policy (a policy without a backing model).

```
authorize :customer, :show
# or for a namespaced policy
authorize [:people, :customer]
```

Another option is to set the policy on the model class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.policy_class
    CustomerPolicy
  end
end
```